# How to put the block title at the center in beamer?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles, beamerposter

In my beamer block the title always comes left alined. Is that possible to make the title of the block centered?

```
\documentclass[final, 12pt]{beamer}    
\usepackage[size=custom,width=120,height=120,scale=1.7,orientation=portrait]{beamerposter} 
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{etoolbox} 

\apptocmd{\frame}{\justifying}{}{}

\usebackgroundtemplate{\centering \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{Figure/LG_PKL.jpg}} 
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.65}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}} 
\addtobeamertemplate{block beamercolorbox begin}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.65}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}

\newenvironment<>{varblock}[2][\textwidth]{% 
  \setlength{\textwidth}{#1} 
  \begin{actionenv}#3% 
  \def\insertblocktitle{#2}% 
  \par% 
  \usebeamertemplate{block begin}} 
{\par% 
  \usebeamertemplate{block end}% 
  \end{actionenv}}

\usecolortheme{rose}

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}


\begin{textblock}{}(0.2,1.15)% 
\begin{varblock}[35cm]{\textbf{1. Introduction}} 
\justifying Space for discussion. 
\end{varblock} 
\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, once again, show a minimal, yet complete version of your document (including `\documentclass`, and all the settings relevant to this particular issue; for example, what kind of blocks are you using).

Comment: After your first comment, I was on the way to edit my question. Sorry. Will remember later.

Comment: Thank you for providing a complete version of the code ;-) Don't forget my other suggestion: revisit your other questions and up-vote good answers and accept those which you consider solved your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your definition of `varblock` to

```
\newenvironment<>{varblock}[2][\textwidth]{% 
  \setlength{\textwidth}{#1} 
  \begin{actionenv}#3% 
  \def\insertblocktitle{\centering#2\par}% 
  \par% 
  \usebeamertemplate{block begin}} 
{\par% 
  \usebeamertemplate{block end}% 
  \end{actionenv}}
```

Answer (score 12):

Actually - I found a much easier way of centering the title within a block. I have to say, I'm not sure if this is sort of hacky, but it works.

```
\begin{block}{\centering 1. Introduction}
...
...
\end{block}
```

I'm imagining it would work similarly for your varblock environment.

```
\begin{varblock}[35cm]{\centering \textbf{1. Introduction}} 
\justifying Space for discussion. 
\end{varblock}
```

Answer (score 3):

As the `block begin` beamertemplate sets the font associated with `block title` before outputting the block title, one can hijack this function to sneak in a `\centering` command instead of redefining the entire template:

```
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={\centering}}
```

This will directly affect all three types of blocks.